# Assign Inserted Identity column to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am going to insert the table from temporary table

```
SELECT D.ID,D.NAME,D.VALUE,T.TOM_ID
 * INTO #TEMP_TBL  
FROM DOM D INNER JOIN TOM T
ON D.ID =T.ID
```

NOW I will insert this temp table records to another table COM(THIS TABLE HAVE IDENTITY FILED OF COM_ID)

`INSERT INTO COM
(
ID,NAME,VALUE
)
FROM SELECT ID ,NAME, VALUE FROM #TEMP_TBL`

Now my requirement is I need to get inserted records identity values(com_id) and
have to refer to other table

```
INSERT INTO TYPE
(
TYPE_ID,COM_ID,NAME,TOM_ID)
SELECT ID,COM_ID(FROM IDENTITY INSERTED IN ABOVE TABLE)NAME,TOM_ID FROM #TEMP_TBL
 )
```

There is more than one record get inserted in every table.How to i find the inserted identity column and assigned this to other.

Comment: I don't fully following what you want to do, but I'm pretty sure it involves the `OUTPUT`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

The rows in table `COM` must be uniquely identified by something other than `com_id`, or you must be willing to order them and deal with duplications. Select from `COM` according to that natural key:

```
select com_id from COM where name = ?  -- or similar
```

Fundamentally, your question is, *how do I get a value in a column from a row?*  There is a temptation to think that there's some magical way to find the produced value of an `identity` column in an inserted row, but in SQL there is no magic, only logic.  To get a value, you have to select it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```sql
SELECT Id, Com_Id, Name, Tom_ID FROM #TEMP_TBL temp INNER JOIN COM C ON C.ID = TBL.ID
```